# Tkinter OptionMenu not displaying properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a tkinter GUI with drop down selection menus. The dropdowns are not displaying fully and only show the full bar when something has been selected (see images below).

The option menus are created with code similar to this:

```
startmonth = StringVar()
p1_PubStartMonth = OptionMenu(DateStartFrame, startmonth, "January", "February", "March", "April",
                                                          "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                                                          "October", "November", "December")
p1_PubStartMonth.configure(width=10, bg=_active)
p1_PubStartMonth.grid(row=5, column=1)
```

Does anyone know what could be causing these widgets to show up this way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want the month to be displayed before any selection is made? If so, I believe you could do something like:  startmonth.set('January')

Comment: @cjonesrun , I don't need a month to be displayed before a selection is made, I just want to know what types of things could be interfering with the button's appearance like in my screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I got he error: `NameError: name '_active' is not defined` and when I deleted the `bg=_active` from the `.configure` it came out just fine.

Also; OptionMenu behaves slightly different depending on if you get if from Tkinter or Ttk.

**Addition**

Since I haven't seen all your code I'll include some code that works for me. If this works for you, then you have something to build upon.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

DateStartFrame = Tk()
startmonth = StringVar()
p1_PubStartMonth = ttk.OptionMenu(DateStartFrame, startmonth,
                              "January", "February", "March", "April",
                              "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                              "October", "November", "December")
p1_PubStartMonth.configure(width=10)
p1_PubStartMonth.grid()
```

Comment: Yes, _active is a variable that contains a hex color code in my project. I should have included that in the example. But in my code, the buttons still don't show up as shown in the screenshots.